# Find the smallest threshold value that is >= K number of data values

Tags: algorithm

A friend of mine was asked this problem in an interview:

> You have two arrays of ints Data (ex. {5, 6, 26, 13, 2}), Thresholds
>   (ex. {19, 2, 6 3}).  You have the int K. Find the smallest Threshold
>   value that is >= K number of data values

I came up with this pseudo code:

```
int[] data
int[] thresholds
int k

//mergesort lowest to highest
sort(data)//O(nlogn)
sort(thresholds)//O(nlogn)

for(i: 0->thresholds.size-1)//O(n)
    if(thresholds[i] >= data[k])
        return thresholds[i]

throw exception("no value found that meets condition")
```

However, my friend (who also came up with a similar solution) was told this solution is not the most efficient solution (as far as run time is concerned).  I can't seem to figure out an obvious better solution than this

**EDIT**:  The smallest value in `threshold` must be `>=` than `k` ***number*** values in `data`.  This means the output value must be compared to `k` different indexes of `data`.

Comment: Is this solution "*not the most efficient*" because its big-O was higher than the rest, or merely because it could be optimized, while still having the same big-O?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding something here: If the threshold is the smallest one that is larger than or equal to k values in `data`, this means it is larger than or equal to the k-th smallest value in the sorted order of `data`. So you are looking for the smallest threshold that is larger than the k-smallest element in `data`.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed not optimal. The problem is equivalent to finding the k-smallest element in the `data` array, which is called the [selection problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm). If you have that, just find the smallest threshold that is larger or equal to that value.

The [median of medians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) algorithm solves it in linear time O(n) and with only O(1) auxiliary space. [Quickselect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) has a quadratic worst case but expected linear time and is much simpler. In C++ you can use [`std::nth_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) for an implementation with linear average case.

You can also use a heap that holds the smallest *k* elements while sliding over the array. This will take time O(n * log k).

Comment: so it is indeed O(n) to find the kth smallest and an additional O(n) for iterating in threshold?

Answer (score 0):

I guess using [Kth Order statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) might help here.
No sorting of threshold or data is needed.

For a given k, you can get `data[k]` without sorting, which is `O(n)` using `selection algorithm`.
Now you iterate through the `threshold`, to find values less than or equal to `data[k]`. that would be `O(n)` again.

Comment: The smallest Threshold value must be >= to K number of values in Data.  This means you have to compare to all values of `data` from indexes `0` to `k`after being ordered.  It can be any `k` indexes.

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc No you only have to look at the k-th element, because it is larger than all the elements 0 to k - 1.

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc  you dont have to. selection algorithm gives you the item at kth element if it were sorted. so anything to left of kth index is less than the value at kth index.